# Dependency Injection - How to resolve a dependency based on the value and not type?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, interface, servicestack

I have one interface and two classes (implemented from that interface) in my application as below:

```
public interface ISMSServiceProvider
{
    NotificationSentResponse Send(SMSMessage sms);
}

public class NexmoProvider: ISMSServiceProvider
{
    NotificationSentResponse Send(SMSMessage sms);
}

public class TwilioProvider: ISMSServiceProvider
{
    NotificationSentResponse Send(SMSMessage sms);
}
```

At some places in my application I need to use NexmoProvider, and at some places TwilioProvider. That's been decided based on the value of a variable of following enum:

```
public enum NotificationProvider
{   
    Twilio = 1,
    Nexmo = 2
}
```

I am using service stack in my application, and having following code to resolve the dependency:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<TwilioProvider, ISMSServiceProvider>();
```

But as you can see there is nothing in ISMSServiceProvider that would allow me to register two different types at the same time.

Could anyone please suggest what changes I may need to do in below structure to enable me using either of Nexmo or Twilio provider classes at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have a **single** registration per Interface or Type so this registration:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<TwilioProvider, ISMSServiceProvider>();
```

Will return an instance of `TwilioProvider` when you resolve from an Interface, e.g:

```
var smsProvider = container.Resolve<ISMSServiceProvider>();
```

If you want to be able to register both types you can register against the concrete Type, e.g:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<TwilioProvider>();
container.RegisterAutoWired<NexmoProvider>();
```

Resolved with:

```
var twilio = container.Resolve<TwilioProvider>();
var nexmo = container.Resolve<NexmoProvider>();
```

If you want to resolve using an Enum you can register a factory, e.g:

```
public class SmsFactory
{
    public ISMSServiceProvider Resolve(NotificationProvider provider) =>
        provider == NotificationProvider.Twilio 
            ? HostConfig.Resolve<TwilioProvider>()
            : HostConfig.Resolve<NexmoProvider>();
}

container.Register(c => new SmsFactory());
```

Which you can inject in your Service with:

```
public SmsFactory SmsFactory { get; set; }
```

Then use as normal, i.e:

```
var smsProvider = SmsFactory.Resolve(NotificationProvider.Twilio);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response mythz... I think the Factory solution looks more sensible in this scenario. Just wondering what package I need to install in order to get "HostConfig"? I am using ServiceStack 3.9.48

Comment: @Nirman When you use the `servicestack` hash tag you're referring to the latest v4 of ServiceStack, you [need to use the servicestack-bsd tag](https://github.com/servicestackv3/servicestackv3#support) to refer to ServiceStack v3. You should be able to use `AppHostBase.Instance.Resolve<T>` or something like that, can't remember.

Comment: thanks, its "AppHostBase.Resolve" which works in v3. Appreciate your help in helping me out with a proper implementation. thank you